# How to link a CSS file in HTML file which is located in another folder

Tags: html, css, ejs

My link looks like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/all.css" type="text/css" />
```

[image]

It is seen from the picture that path of the `header.ejs` file is `/views/partials/header.ejs`, while `all.css` file located at `styles/all.css`. How to link these both files?

Comment: you can try to put `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../styles/all.css" type="text/css" />`

Comment: Remember you have to link CSS using path from main file, not location of header file.

Comment: My header.ejs is included into landing page which I want to be styled. Does not it work?

Comment: What if I want all.css is workable for every html file where header.ejs is included?

Comment: why is it ok not to have a body tag?

Answer (score 1):

Change it to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../styles/all.css" type="text/css" />
```

**Explanation**:
If you go only one folder back from your `header.ejs` file, you are in the folder `views`. There is no `styles` folder stored there. So you need to go one more folder back.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../styles/all.css" type="text/css" />
```

to go up to the personal_website directory before going to /style/all.css

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../styles/all.css" type="text/css" />
```

That should work.

- Is the image in the same directory as the file referencing it?
- Is the image in a directory **below**?
- Is the image in a directory **above**?

By "below" and "above", I mean subdirectories and parent directories. Relative file paths give us a way to travel in both directions. Take a look at my primitive example:
[image]

Here is all you need to know about relative file paths:

- Starting with "/" returns to the root directory and starts there
- Starting with "../" moves one directory backwards and starts there
- Starting with "../../" moves two directories backwards and starts
  there (and so on...)
- To move forward, just start with the first subdirectory and keep
  moving forward

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a `<body>` tag before the `<div>`.

Comment: Please explain what effect that would have and why it solves the problem.